# getting FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] while renaming the file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, rename

i am trying to rename pdf file(content inside it) while extracting the information from the pdf file here is m code below.i am getting error **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Z:\india\1953780.pdf' -> 'Z:\india\GEM/2020/B/862094.pdf'**

```
image_directory = "pdf_files"
document_elements = []
image_directory_abspath = os.path.abspath(r"Z:\india")
list = os.listdir(image_directory_abspath) # dir is your directory path
number_files = len(list)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(image_directory_abspath):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".pdf")]:
        parse_entire_pdf = parser.from_file(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), xmlContent=True)
        for key, values in parse_entire_pdf.items():
            if key == 'content':
                bid_number = regex.search(r'(Bid Number:)\W(GEM\W\d{4}\W[A-Z]\W\d+)', values)
                if bid_number is None:
                    bid_number=regex.search(r'(RA Number:)\W(GEM\W\d{4}\W[A-Z]+\W\d+)', values)
                try:
                     print(bid_number.group(2))
                     os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), os.path.join(dirpath, bid_number.group(2) + '.pdf'))
```

Comment: try replacing the slashes by backslashes in your output path

Comment: otherwise, I would check that the directory `Z:\india\GEM/2020/B/` exists

Comment: thanks fo the help i changed \ with _ and it worked.

Comment: Great, should I make an answer out of this to close the question?